# Correct use of section article and heading

Tags: css, html, slider

I wrote some code for an advanced liquid slider. But as my header slider contains some major content like h-tags p-tags and some images. I asked myself "can I consider each slide as an article". Because I can't find the correct answer maybe somebody can help me. The question is, is my code correctly nested and the right use of Semantic Elements. The code is:

```
 <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div id="main-slider" class="liquid-slider">    
            <article id="slider-1" class="liquid-slide-wrapper" style="background: url(images/back-99.jpg) 50% 50% /cover; repeat:no-repeat; min-height:450px;">
                <section class="section-text-left">
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="title" style=" color:#f7740a; display:none;">Professionele, betaalbare website nodig?</h2>
                        <h2 style=" color:#fff; display:none;">Zelf uw website aanpassen?</h3>
                    </header>
                    <p style="display:none; color:#fff;">Onze unieke websites worden afgeleverd met een wordpress CMS systeem.<br>
                        Hiermee kan u zelf uw website aanpassen!<br> Vat de kudu bij de horens en contacteer ons voor meer info!
                    </p>
                    <p style="display:none;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Mail Ons</button>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-transparent btn-lg">0494 / 77 22 61</button></p>
                </section>
                <section class="section-img-right clearfix">
                    <img class="slider-img-right fadeInRight animated" style="display:none; width:100%; max-width:692px; height:auto;" src="images/imac.png" />
                    <img class="slider-img-right fadeIn animated-slow" style="display:none; width:100%; max-width:692px; height:auto;" src="images/straf-webdesign.png" />
                    <img class="slider-img-right fadeIn animated-slow" style="display:none; width:100%; max-width:692px; height:auto;" src="images/responsive-webdesign.png" />
                </section>      
            </article>
            <article id="slider-2" style="background: url(images/background-7.png) 50% 50% /cover; repeat:no-repeat; min-height:450px;">
                <section class="section-text-left">
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="title" style=" color:#f7740a; display:none;">JustOnWeb wordt Kudu Concepts!</h2>
                        <h2 style="display:none; color:#000;">Een nieuwe naam, met een professionelere aanpak!</h3>
                    <header>
                    <p style="display:none; color:#fff;">Een website bestaat uit meer dan een lay-out. <br>Met kudu Concepts gaan we verder daar waar anderen stoppen!<br>
                        We bedenken een volledige filosofie voor uw website en <br> combineren dit met onze kennis van Online Marketing!
                    </p>
                </section>
            </article>
          </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to W3School semantic here : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

< section > contain < article >
it is not recommanded to use < section > inside < article > and inside < header >
According W3C, a section is "a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading."

< header > is on top of parent element, so on top of body (the header) but also on top of sections or articles or any other div

In your code :
< h1 > should be close with < / h1 > and not h2, same for < h2 >

Comment: So the header element inside my section can be correct?

Comment: Yes, it specifies a header for a document or section. Every thing is on the link I send

Comment: Is it the correct way to implement these elements in a content slider?

Comment: I'm not that good at content slider but if you correct the points I've talked about, it should work fine :)

Comment: And here : class="section-img-right clearfix" don't forget that if you put a space in class name, it mean that you have two classes, here : 1)section-img-right and 2)clearfix

Comment: In the same page, W3Schools says:
"Can we use the definitions to decide how to nest those elements? No, we cannot!

So, you will find HTML pages with <section> elements containing <article> elements, and <article> elements containing <section> elements."